# How to configure WebStorm to not wrap comments to the next line

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have the following in my code:

```
"no-sequences": ["error"], // Disallow Use of the Comma Operator
"no-throw-literal": ["error"], // Restrict what can be thrown as an exception
```

After I reformat my code with `Ctrl+Alt+L` I get the following:

```
"no-sequences": [
  "error"
],
// Disallow Use of the Comma Operator
"no-throw-literal": [
  "error"
],
// Restrict what can be thrown as an exception
```

As you can see, the comments are wrapped to next line.

Is there any way to configure WebStorm to not wrap comments or put them before the corresponding code, and not after?

Comment: Please share your Code Style together with sample file. With my settings (not a JS person .. so nothing special here and no extra JS-related plugins) formatting does not change much (only alignment on `:`) -- comments remain as they are.

Comment: @LazyOne, how do you want me to share Code Style? As a screenshot?

Comment: No -- as a config file that can easily be copied over. You can either use `File | Export Settings` and specify only desired options or just find that  individual config file manually -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: @LazyOne, [here is](http://www.filedropper.com/codestyle) the file with code style settings, and [the sample JSON file](http://www.filedropper.com/example_1)

Comment: Those files have 0 length when trying to download it (tried Firefox & Chrome). Maybe its just my OS (maybe my KAV does interfere here somehow?). Please use another service (Dropbox/Google Drive/MS OneDrive/etc)

Comment: Actually, I think there is no need for those files any more. I've tried it in JSON file .. and have the same behaviour -- although in JavaScript it works just fine.

Comment: 1) There is no options for comments for JSON files 2) Check this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1124#comment=27-412525 3) In such circumstances (standalone JSON file + no formatter options for comments for this file type) I may only suggest to submit Feature Request ticket to the Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB 4) But if the issue still happens in JavaScript context/file -- then please provide those files.

Comment: @LazyOne, thank you. The behavior is specific and only happens to JSON file. I'll think about the options you outlined